# How to stop arduino\esp8266 Hotspots

Tags: arduino, android-wifi, esp8266, arduino-esp8266

I have D1 wifi (with esp8266) microcontroller and I created hot spot using

```
#include <ESP8266WiFi.h>
#include <WiFiClient.h>
```

libraries.
Code of creating the hot spot:

```
WiFiServer serverWF(80);

WiFi.softAP(ssidHS, passwordHS);    // Creating the hotspo
serverWF.begin();
```

How do I close/stop the hot spot.

Bouth `serverWF.close();` and  `serverWF.stop();`
not working.

Answer (score 2):

The solution:

You should use

```
WiFi.mode(WIFI_OFF);
```

The hot spot will disappear from your list of wifi.

The variable `serverWF` responsible for the server and not the hot spot